# Интерполяция функции двух аргументов python. Как в итоге получить функцию в каждой отдельно запрашиваемой точке?

Tags: python

У меня есть два массива: x и y (разного размера). И массив значений в каждой точке (x,y) из этих массивов. Я хочу получить интерполяцией функцию, которая может выводить значение функции в любой запрашиваемой точке в пределах интерполяции. Причем, не один раз.
Функция interp2d запрашивает на вход массивы и не может выдать значение в конкретной точке.
Скажите, пожалуйста, каким методом следует реализовывать интерполяцию и возможно ли это на python вообще?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: хотя бы пример что на входе и что предполагается на выходе приведите

Comment: Ну подайте ей массивы из одной точки, в чём проблема? Судя по подробному описанию функции `interp2d` вам нужна именно она, там прямо все шаги ведь расписаны: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Answer (score 3):

Стесняюсь спросить, а документацию вы хоть читали?

interp2d действительно значения в конкретной точке не выдает. Но зато строит (возвращает) функцию. А уже эта функция выдает значения в любой точке. Причем пример есть прямо в документации.

Вот немного адаптировал:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.sin (X) * np.sin (Y) / (X * Y)
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, Z, kind='cubic')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)

xnew = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.7)
ynew = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.7)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(xnew, ynew)
Z=f(xnew,ynew)
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z,c='red')
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значение 0.7 взято специально, что-бы показать, что это точки, которых нет в обучающем наборе.

И да, при запуске скрипта строится трехмерная картинка, которую можно интерактивно "крутить".

Comment: В конце не хватает plt.show()

Comment: Для того что бы подавить сообщение об ошибке рекомендуют заменить строку ax = Axes3D(fig) на две строки 
ax = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)
fig.add_axes(ax)

Comment: При работе в IDE (практически любой) plt.show()  давать не обязательно. Хотя да, канонически его надо использовать.  О каком сообщении об ошибке идет  речь?